# Sql query to move data into Hbase

Tags: sql, hadoop, hbase

I am planning to move my data into **hbase** but there are so many logic in **stored procedure** that i found it will be easy to move my data to hbase using **SQL** language, but how can i do that. I didn't found anything. Please help

Comment: you want to migrate your tables from relational db to hbase ?

Comment: i want to know after using stored procedure the data i want to move to RDBMS i want the same data to be moved to HBASE. How can i do that ?

Comment: @NirmalRam please give some input

Comment: why stored procedure why not [sqoop](https://dataandstats.wordpress.com/2014/12/08/rdbms-to-hbase-through-sqoop/) ? infact, sqoop will run mapreduce to do this job quickly. see [this](https://coderwall.com/p/kgrwwq/sqoop-data-transfer-tool-from-rdbms-to-hadoop-box)

Comment: @RamPrasadG Thanks this looks much better option.